# How to avoid content from being cut while printing

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, google-chrome

I am trying to print an `N` number of images in a pdf, but I can't manage to avoid my images from being cut.
I tried using `{ page-break-inside: avoid }` in the div class but it did not work. I leave a code pen for debugging hope it helps.

PS: I added the `margin-right: 0` to the `@page` because I need the images to use all the blank space in the page

https://codepen.io/lsvargas/pen/mdJedNy

Comment: You want to print the *html* rendered as a pdf by a *pdf printer driver* built-in or (otherwise from the OS) from the browser? For full control you might want to consider rendering the pdf thru code. Such libaries exist though i dont know specifically the best one for your use case.

Comment: @GetSet I want to use the one from the browser

Comment: Possibly a media query could be a solution, for *print*? Considering that users print page dimensions differ, i dont know. Still think rendering the pdf thru code gives the exact requirements in a solution. There was a library i came across once that rendered basic html to pdf server side.

Comment: @GetSet i want to avoid server side rendering till the end, besides I think there should be a way to use the tools that the browser gives and accomplish the goal in a much easier way and without external libraries

Comment: If you want to avoid server side rendering then you have to ask your yourself, do the users *care* if an image is broken (by a page break) on pdf browser side? If they dont care then nor should you. How to deal with an image that height wise expands 2 or more pages?

Comment: @GetSet the size of the image is always fixed in this case, I think i will endup making a container with the page dimensions and just filling it with a fixed number of images and so on..